# Running R scripts on a Linux cluster

Tags: linux, cluster, r

I have access to an IBM IDataplex Cluster with CentOS v.6.2. If I want to run the following R script on R:

```
library(data.table) library(mgcv) library(reshape2) library(dplyr) 
library(tidyr) library(lubridate) library(DataCombine)

temp_hist <- as.data.table(temp_hist)
humid_hist <- as.data.table(humid_hist)

# Merge
mykey<- c("FIPS", "year","month", "week")
setkeyv(temp_hist, mykey)
setkeyv(humid_hist, mykey)

hist<- merge(temp_hist, humid_hist, by=mykey)

# Min
hist_min <- hist

hist_min$FIPS <- hist_min$year <- hist_min$month <- hist_min$tmax <- hist_min$tmean <- hist_min$hmax <- hist_min$hmean <- NULL

# Adding Factors
hist_min$citycode <- rep(101,nrow(hist_min)) 
hist_min$year <- rep(2010,nrow(hist_min))
hist_min$week <- rep(1,nrow(hist_min)) 
hist_min$lnincome <- rep(10.262,nrow(hist_min))

# Predictions
pred_hist_min <- predict.gam(gam_mean_count_wk, hist_min)

pred_hist_min <- as.data.table(pred_hist_min)
pred_hist_min <- cbind(hist, pred_hist_min)
pred_hist_min$tmax <- pred_hist_min$tmean <- pred_hist_min$tmin <- pred_hist_min$hmax <- pred_hist_min$hmean <- pred_hist_min$hmin <- NULL

# Aggregate by FIPS
min_hist <- pred_hist_min %>%
  group_by(FIPS) %>%
  summarise(pred_hist = mean(pred_hist_min))
```

How do I utilise the performance of the cluster (specifying cores) using qsub/bsub to run this script?

Comment: Would something like [Rmpi](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rmpi/index.html) work for you?

Comment: I can't seem to install Rmpi on my the cluster. Are there any other solutions? Thanks!

Comment: Sure, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/1395309/350713

Comment: Thanks again. I'll check out the packages. Do I not need use bsub or qsub beforehand?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure. Maybe talk to the people who run the cluster?